# What type of model should I fit to increase accuracy?

Tags: deep-learning, recurrent-neural-networks, long-short-term-memory, deep-neural-networks

Currently, I'm working on 6-axis IMU(Inertial Measurment Unit) dataset. [This dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/dasmehdixtr/carla-driver-behaviour-dataset) contain 6 axis IMU data of 7 different drivers. The Imu sensor attached on vehicle. The drivers drives same path. So, the dataset include 6 feature columns and a label column.

I tried multiple neural network models.The sensor data is a sequential data so I tried LSTM(Long Short Term Memory) & classical fully-connected layers.
Some of my architecture(in keras framework):

---

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   

lstm_4 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 128)            69120     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_5 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 64)             49408     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_6 (LSTM)                (None, 1, 32)             12416     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_8 (Dense)              (None, 1, 64)             2112      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 1, 64)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 1, 7)              455       


2nd Architecture:

=================================================================
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 32)                224       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 64)                2112      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_12 (Dense)             (None, 128)               8320      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 256)               33024     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 512)               131584    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_15 (Dense)             (None, 256)               131328    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 128)               32896     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 64)                8256      
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)             (None, 128)               8320      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 7)                 903
```

The best accuracy in my models was %70 which is not good. How style of layers should I use to handle this data? Or, which type of model would increase accuracy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after reading some literature in the area I'd recommend the following:

- Try using Convolution Neural Networks (CNNs) [this](https://wiki.tum.de/download/attachments/242090417/IMU_Sensor_Fusion_With_ML.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1562329774913&api=v2) paper outlines some really good points on why should you use CNNs.
- Try a Combination of the different layers in the same model. Start with some Convolution Layers, then some LSTMs and then a couple of Dense Layers followed by Dropout